# ERR.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR - Unable to perform air booking step

Tags: sabre

We are getting an error "ERR.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR - Unable to perform air booking step" in CreatePassengerNameRecordRS in TEST mode.

Please have a look at the log file which contains all request and response logs and let us know why we are getting the error message.

```
{
  "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "targetCity": "T4QK",
    "haltOnAirPriceError": true,
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
      "AgencyInfo": {
        "Address": {
          "AddressLine": "SABRE TRAVEL",
          "CityName": "SOUTHLAKE",
          "CountryCode": "US",
          "PostalCode": "76092",
          "StateCountyProv": {
            "StateCode": "TX"
          },
          "StreetNmbr": "3150 SABRE DRIVE"
        },
        "Ticketing": {
          "TicketType": "7TAW"
        }
      },
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "ContactNumbers": {
          "ContactNumber": [
            {
              "NameNumber": "1.1",
              "Phone": "9632314151",
              "PhoneUseType": "H"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Email": [
          {
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "Address": "sunnytiwd@gmail.com"
          }
        ],
        "PersonName": [
          {
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "Infant": false,
            "NameReference": "AB1231",
            "PassengerType": "ADT",
            "GivenName": "manoj Mr",
            "Surname": "sharma"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AirBook": {
      "HaltOnStatus": [
        {
          "Code": "HL"
        },
        {
          "Code": "KK"
        },
        {
          "Code": "LL"
        },
        {
          "Code": "NN"
        },
        {
          "Code": "NO"
        },
        {
          "Code": "UC"
        },
        {
          "Code": "US"
        }
      ],
      "OriginDestinationInformation": {
        "FlightSegment": [
          {
            "DepartureDateTime": "2023-09-29T06:55:00",
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2023-09-29T09:00:00",
            "FlightNumber": "780",
            "NumberInParty": "1",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "G",
            "Status": "NN",
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "TLV"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "SAW"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "PC",
              "FlightNumber": "780"
            }
          },
          {
            "DepartureDateTime": "2023-11-21T13:45:00",
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2023-11-21T14:55:00",
            "FlightNumber": "783",
            "NumberInParty": "1",
            "ResBookDesigCode": "G",
            "Status": "NN",
            "OriginLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "SAW"
            },
            "DestinationLocation": {
              "LocationCode": "TLV"
            },
            "MarketingAirline": {
              "Code": "PC",
              "FlightNumber": "783"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "RedisplayReservation": {
        "NumAttempts": 10,
        "WaitInterval": 300
      }
    },
    "AirPrice": [
      {
        "PriceRequestInformation": {
          "Retain": true,
          "OptionalQualifiers": {
            "FOP_Qualifiers": {
              "BasicFOP": {
                "Type": "CASH"
              }
            },
            "PricingQualifiers": {
              "PassengerType": [
                {
                  "Code": "ADT",
                  "Quantity": "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "SpecialReqDetails": {
      "SpecialService": {
        "SpecialServiceInfo": {
          "AdvancePassenger": [
            {
              "Document": {
                "Number": "",
                "IssueCountry": "",
                "NationalityCountry": "IN",
                "Type": "P"
              },
              "PersonName": {
                "NameNumber": "1.1",
                "GivenName": "manoj",
                "MiddleName": "",
                "Surname": "sharma",
                "DateOfBirth": "1979-08-12",
                "Gender": "M"
              },
              "SegmentNumber": "A"
            }
          ],
          "SecureFlight": [
            {
              "PersonName": {
                "NameNumber": "1.1",
                "GivenName": "manoj",
                "Surname": "sharma",
                "DateOfBirth": "1979-08-12",
                "Gender": "M"
              },
              "SegmentNumber": "A",
              "VendorPrefs": {
                "Airline": {
                  "Hosted": true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "PostProcessing": {
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "SP TEST"
        }
      },
      "RedisplayReservation": {
        "waitInterval": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```